# Telegram Sirikit not able to talk to bot

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, siri, sirikit

I was using Siri integration with telegram. I can ask Siri to send a message to any individual using telegram and it does so. But if I ask it to send a message to a bot using botname it keeps asking whom to send message to and doesn't select bot name to send message to.

Working: "Telegram personname Hi"

Not Working: "Telegram botname Hi"

Is this suppose to happen, Any ideas how can I get it to work.